# Analyse CSV File in GUI

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

Good people of StackOverflow, I recently started using this package/Python and I encountered a couple of bumps on the way. The logic of my program is to import a CSV file into the user interface then have a run button that will perform a couple of task e.g. like evaluate strings etc. I want to do this in the data_manipulation. I can't seem to be able to get the data frame, to analyse it. Could someone advise what is wrong with the code below? Thank you in advance for any reply. :)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import pandas as pd
import csv


class main:
    def __init__(self, csv_file_path, df):
        global v

    def import_csv_data(self):
        self.csv_file_path = askopenfilename()
        v.set(self.csv_file_path)
        self.df = pd.read_csv(self.csv_file_path)

    def data_manipulation(self):
        print(self.df)


root = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(root, text="File Path").grid(row=0, column=0)
v = tk.StringVar()
entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=v).grid(row=0, column=1)
tk.Button(root, text="Browse Data Set", command=main.import_csv_data).grid(row=1, column=0)
tk.Button(root, text="Close", command=root.destroy).grid(row=1, column=1)
tk.Button(root, text="Run", command=main.data_manipulation).grid(row=1, column=2)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You would need to tell us what is happening that you don't expect, or what is not happening that you'd expect to happen. "I can't seem to be able to get the data frame" isn't quite enough.

Comment: Hey AKX, Thank you for looking into this. I just want to be able to refer the df into my function data_manipulation. At the moment, I want to just print the data frame, after I want to evaluate the strings e.g. code values and then end up with a new file. At the moment the error I am getting is TypeError: import_csv_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'. I hope this makes sense :) Many thanks again for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to use a class as if it was an instance of that class.

While you wouldn't necessarily need a class at all for a program like this, we can still refactor it as one deriving from `tk.Tk()`. This also obviates the need for global variables.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import pandas as pd
import csv


class DataAnalysisApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.csv_file_path = None
        self.df = None
        self.build_ui()

    def import_csv_data(self):
        path = askopenfilename()
        if not path:
            return
        self.csv_file_path = path
        self.entry_var.set(self.csv_file_path)
        self.df = pd.read_csv(self.csv_file_path)

    def data_manipulation(self):
        print(self.df)

    def build_ui(self):
        tk.Label(self, text="File Path").grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.entry_var = tk.StringVar()
        entry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.entry_var).grid(row=0, column=1)
        tk.Button(self, text="Browse Data Set", command=self.import_csv_data).grid(row=1, column=0)
        tk.Button(self, text="Close", command=self.destroy).grid(row=1, column=1)
        tk.Button(self, text="Run", command=self.data_manipulation).grid(row=1, column=2)


app = DataAnalysisApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Wow! You are a treasure!!! I can't thank you enough.

Comment: Better check whether `askopenfilename()` actually returns a path because user can select `Cancel` in the dialog.  Then there may be error when calling `pd.read_csv()` using the empty string returned.